# Prototype Cell width runs off the page in a Table View

Tags: xcode, uitableview

Fairly new to coding and this is my first post here. I added a Prototype Cell to a Table View Cell but when I run the project the cell runs off the page (on the right)? Does anyone have any help they can provide?

This is the ViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ConsultationsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
        ConsultationFunctions.readConsultations(completion: { [weak self] in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Data.consultationModels.count
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ConsutationsTableViewCell
        
        cell.setup(consultationModel: Data.consultationModels[indexPath.row])
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }
}
```

And this is the TableViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class ConsutationsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        
        cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        cardView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
    
    func setup(consultationModel: ConsultationModel) {
        titleLabel.text = consultationModel.title
    }
}
```

I've tried adjusting the Storyboards Identity, Attributes and Size Inspectors as best I can but just don't understand where I've gone wrong? Any guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the interface constraints in your code, so I guess you have them in the Storyboard, or ar least you should.

I suggest you to go through some tutorials or guides to "Add New Constraints" for **cardView** and **titleLabel**. Here you have a simple one:

https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/custom-cells/